# How to add a checkbox column to a control that is inherited from ASP.NET DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I've read a lot of articles about how to add a checkbox column to a DataGrid from **within a page**, but I can't find anything about how to add the column when inheriting the control itself.

Essentially, I know I need to create a class that inherits from `ITemplate`. Something along these lines:

```
public class SelectionCheckBoxTemplate : ITemplate {
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        var checkbox = new CheckBox(...);

        container.Controls.Add(checkbox);
    }
}
```

And then, this template needs to be added to a TemplateColumn object:

```
var checkBoxTemplate = new TemplateColumn();

checkBoxTemplate.ItemTemplate = new SelectionCheckBoxTemplate();
```

However, this is where I get stuck. All the articles now show adding this `TemplateColumn` object to the Page's DataGrid control. But what if I'm extending the DataGrid by inheriting from it? I tried adding this TemplateColumn to the Columns property from within `OnPreRender`, but nothing happens. `SelectionCheckBoxTemplate`'s `InstantiateIn()` method is never fired. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging and trying different solutions, I discovered that the column needs to be added in virtual `CreateColumnSet()` method. Doesn't seem like this is documented anywhere:

```
    protected override ArrayList CreateColumnSet(PagedDataSource source, bool useDataSource)
    {
        var columns = base.CreateColumnSet(source, useDataSource);

        var checkboxTemplate = new TemplateColumn();
        checkboxTemplate.ItemTemplate = ...;

        columns.Insert(0, checkboxTemplate);

        return columns;
    }
```